# Big-O notation how to work through it php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, big-o

Ok I am just learning about Big-O and someone gave me a conceptual question, to take as a means of trying to learn. However just barely starting out with Big-O I only know concept per say.

I've been told If I take an array of sorted INT values how would I write a function that essentially would return true (or false) if the sum of any two of the numbers in the array equal zero. So my assumption is I would have an array like.

```
array("0","1","2","3","4")
```

Just an example Im sure the array is much larger. What I am trying to figure out how is how can I really do that? I don't want to iterate over the array x times where x is the count of the array and then some to try every combination, thats just insane and if the array is large enough all Ill do is run out of memory and either bottle neck myself server side or client side depending on the route I run with it javascript or php.

So whats a good way of tackling that cause I sure have no decent clue at the moment.

Comment: Think a little about what you need to get two integers to *sum* to zero. Write some examples that are true and some that are a lot like them but false. Then think a lot more...

Comment: array of SORTED int values... this is very important :)

Comment: Why is iterating over the array trying every combination "insane"?  Can you think of a better way of evaluating the sum of every pair?

Comment: Sounds like a phone interview question...

Comment: I think it originated off a phone interview, for me someone asked me if I understood big-o notation and I had told them no I was unfamiliar with it. Talking to one of my tech buddies that was tryin to give me a means of solving it on my own recited a question to me, which hes part of a hiring team in his co, so its plausible its an interview question in general. But in all, between someone asking me then getting that line of question from someone else, its set me on a path to want to know more. But I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head completely around it so here I am :-D

Comment: As for iterating over an array in every possible combination. I only lead that to potential memory issues, and time constraints. Most of the work I have done, people want the answer within a second anything long is to much, that and if the array is large enough I can picture running out of memory in one form or another. But since Im new to this line of logic and not having worked with such large arrays much its only a guess at best, I could be wrong might not take much memory or process time as I might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's sorted, you can find the value closest to zero in O(log(n)) time through [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). That value splits the array in two subarrays, one with values less than zero (call it *A*) and one with values greater than zero (call it *B*). Obvisouly, two values *a* and *b* sum up to zero if and only if *a* = -*b*. So you can do:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
while (i < A.length && j < B.length) {
    if (A[i] == -B[j]) {
         return true;
    } else if (A[i] < -B[j]) {
        i++;
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
return false;
```

The complexity of the algorithm above is O(n/2)=O(n), and since O(n) > O(log(n)) (binary search), then the overall complexity is still O(n). Note then, that you could have iterated over the array instead of using binary search and the complexity would have been the same.

That actually makes me think you can do it all in a single loop. Just keep two pointers, one at the start of the array, one at the end, and move the progressively towards the middle. Complexity is is still O(n/2) = O(n):

```
var i = myArray.length-1;
var j = 0;
while (i > j) {
    if (myArray[i] == -myArray[j]) {
         return true;
    } else if (myArray[i] > -myArray[j]) {
        i--;
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Or you could work outside in, `int i = 0, j = n-1; if (a[i] > 0 || a[j] < 0) { return false; } while(i < j) { if ((s = a[i] + b[j]) == 0) { return true; } else if (s < 0) { ++i; } else { --j; } } return false;`.

Answer (score 3):

Big O notation is about classifying how "intense" certain algorithms are.

To take your example of a poor algorithm to solve that problem, you have `n` elements of an array, and one way to see if any combination of elements sums to zero is for each `1` element, check all of the other `n-1` elements for the zero sum.

Big O ignores the constants, so "for each element" = `n` you check `n` elements, and get `O(n*n)` or `O(n^2)`.

Like you said, there's probably a better way. Since the array is sorted, try to think of some *properties* of that array, like big numbers at one end and small at the other.

That should help you think of an algorithm that has a lower complexity than `O(n^2)`.